# MySQL: how can i push data onto existing column data?

Tags: mysql, arrays, push

si have a db field that i want to use to track intervals.  i want to push completed intervals onto the db field when they are completed.  to wit:

```sql
intervals = '10'
intervals = '1020'   <-- pushing 20 onto the field
intervals = '102040'   <-- pushing 40 onto the field
intervals = '102040SP'   <-- pushing SP onto the field
```

the values will never decrement (and order doesn't really matter, if that's a factor), so i'm only looking for a way to `UPDATE` the field, but i have no idea how to do that because `UPDATE tbl SET ...` just overwrites the existing contents.  i looked into `CONCAT`, but that works with variables the user provides, not with existing data AND additional user data.  if i were to write some PSEUDO code, it might look like this:

```php
UPDATE tbl PUSHTO intervals VALUE newInterval WHERE id='id' AND date='date'
```

so.  can anybody help me out here?  there has to be a way to do this.  :)

Comment: What's wrong with `CONCAT(interval, newInterval)`?

Comment: i thought you had to provide the two values.  i didn't know you could just supply a column name and a value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update with concatenation is what you want here:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET interval = CONCAT(interval, newInterval)
WHERE id = 'id' AND date = 'date';
```

If you wanted to make the update even in the event that `newInterval` might be `null`, you could try:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET interval = CONCAT(interval, COALESCE(newInterval, ''))
WHERE id = 'id' AND date = 'date';
```

Comment: but `interval` is IN the db already.  `newInterval` is what i want to push on, or conactenate to, `interval`.  this still works?  how does it pull `interval` from the db?  curious *how* it works.  :)  also i noted, i missed the 's' in my psuedo code... :P

Comment: The `SET` statement is replacing `interval` by itself, with `newInterval` concatenated at the end.  That is all.

Comment: well holy crap.  that's awesome!  i didn't see in the docs that you could just use the column name as you did.  i'll have to dig deeper, i guess.  thanks so much!

Comment: is there a way to check if `newInterval` already exists?  i'm thinking not for this project, but for a future one where this would apply.

Comment: One option would be to use `COALESCE` to effectively "ignore" `newInterval` in the event that it be empty or `null`.